# Counting the number of records returned

Tags: mysql

I have the following code to tell me if a record with "widgets_active" in the option_name column of the table wp_options exists.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "options";
    $ActiveWidgets ="widgets_active";
    $CheckAllActiveWidgets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `option_name` FROM '$table_name' WHERE `option_name` = '$ActiveWidgets'");

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$CheckAllActiveWidgets.'");</script>';

    if (mysql_num_rows($CheckAllActiveWidgets) == 0) {
```

However, when I run the function the alert simply says 'Array' and the error

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array
>   given.... on line 6...

is displayed, if I run just the SQL statment mySQL it does return the 1 record that I placed there. How can I fix the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to do a count in the SQL itself.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "options";
    $CheckAllActiveWidgets = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'siteorigin_widgets_active'");

    if ($CheckAllActiveWidgets == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of an expert with Wordpress, but according to Wordpress documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) you should be able to count the results of your query using `$wpdb->num_rows`. So your code should be something linke this:

```
global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "options";
    $ActiveWidgets ="widgets_active";
    $CheckAllActiveWidgets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `option_name` FROM '$table_name' WHERE `option_name` = '$ActiveWidgets'");

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$CheckAllActiveWidgets.'");</script>';

    if ($wpdb->num_rows == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$CheckAllActiveWidgets` holds an array!

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $CheckAllActiveWidgets[0][0] . '");</script>';
```

`

Comment: Thanks but the alert is just a debugging alert, I really need to resolve the Warning notice.

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: what about: if (!$CheckAllActiveWidgets) {